# Printing the output in Javascript Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

From the function I want to get the output of the "remains" but unable to get it. I am getting the result as `console.log` but i want it to print.

I tried using `document.write()` but still it says "Your code didn't print anything."

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(java.math);
importPackage(java.util);

var sc = new Scanner(System["in"]);
var N = sc.nextInt();
var M = sc.nextInt();
var total = 0;

function remains(){
   for( let i = 1; i<=N; i++){
      total = total + i;
      remainder = M - total;
  }
}

remains();
print(remainder);
```

I want to print the output of the remainder.

Comment: The `remainder` variable only exists inside of your `Remains()`-function.

Comment: I am getting the output as console.log() outside the function but it is not printing

Comment: Are you looking for `System.out.println`?

Comment: Btw, you should declare your `remainder` variable with `var`, next to the `var total`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Hmm. Your program runs fine on https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-rhino-online. Input `1` and `3` prints `2`

Comment: @JohnDoe yes,It is working fine in jdoodle. I don't know the reason why it isn't getting compiled in the particular compiler.

Comment: @Bergi I tried it doesn't work